# Why did my "useful" comment get deleted?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I commented on this question: [CSS Counters add 1 to counter-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68562954/8620333) in order to know what the OP wants to make sure to grab the suitable duplicate, but I don't see my comment any more.

I asked the OP if "X" solves their issue (as I think it is) before closing as duplicate.

I don't think my comment can be seen as "no longer needed", "unfriendly" or "something else" so why it was deleted?

Comment: Every comment can be deleted at any time. I also see an answer there, did your comment suggest the same method that the answer provides?

Comment: @BDL at any time but not when I am asking about clarification and the OP didn't reply to me and it have been only few hours

Comment: @BDL also I don't see how the answer provided is related to my comment?

Comment: well, next time I will simply close as duplicate and move on ...

Comment: [r/suspiciousquotes](https://www.reddit.com/r/suspiciousquotes/top/?t=all). I would have edited the `"`s with `'`s but that would be a minor edit

Comment: I have sympathy for your case. You're a gold badger so your dupe close would have hammered it close in one go. If you are second guessing yourself then I admire it that you don't jump the gun and ask in a comment first. It is then a little infuriating when someone else decides for you that this comment needs to be deleted. But this is basically collateral damage. This is how comments are treated and as Makoto says, they can be deleted at any time. Can't do much about it, we don't have types of comments to distinguish their intent.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you ask them something custom like "Does ``this code`` solve your problem?" or write an actual "Does this answer your question? <link>" dupe-vote comment yourself? I find the latter to work rather well when I don't want to hammer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi more like the first one and the link was not an SO question but a documentation link

Comment: I've had a custom close vote comment flagged and deleted before, while the question was still awaiting votes. There really is nothing sacred when it comes to comments.

Answer (score 7):

Comments are temporal.  They can be deleted at any time for any reason.

Comment: well, comment are meant to ask for clarification. I don't see why my comment got deleted after only few hours. I am not talking about days

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you comment was addressed by the asker editing the post, your comment becomes obsolete, so it can be safely deleted.

Comment: @Braiam no it was not. I am aware about obsolete comments. I aksed a question and in less than 4h my comment got deleted and I never got a reply. I also think that OP never saw my comment. due to the deletion

Comment: @TemaniAfif did OP edited the question? If it did, then it did addressed your question.

Comment: @Braiam no edit too.

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  I didn't specify that comments had a specific TTL.  The assumption should always be that a comment can and will be deleted for arbitrary reasons.

Comment: If someone asks "why did someone shut my window", then "windows can be shut at any time for any reason" is not an answer. Or some other analogy.

Comment: @khelwood:  Except in this case, we're not talking about windows.  We're talking about comments on Stack Overflow, which have a very specific and narrow use case, and a very narrow lifespan.  A lot of people want to give more weight to comments than there actually is, when the blunt reality is that a comment *can* be deleted, and anything of actual value should be preserved in answers instead.

Comment: @Makoto Obviously comments *can* be deleted. I don't think that is in dispute. Some comments are deleted, and some remain. Presumably there's some kind of rationale distinguishing between the two, or why have comments at all? Why not have every comment immediately disappear as soon it is posted?

Comment: @Makoto Comments have a very narrow lifespan. Except when they don't. There are comments that have lasted 10+ years... so this is not a particularly useful observation.

Answer (score 7):

It was flagged as "no longer needed", so I deleted it as it looked to me like it was no longer needed.

If it's important post it as an answer, or if that's not appropriate, make it clearer what the link is to and why you are posting it as a comment.

Comment: Well at least we have a proper dupe target for "Why was my comment deleted" questions now :-)

Comment: the link is not important, before the link I was asking a question and I provided a link related to my question ... I have a duplicate and I want to make sure I understood the question correctly so waiting for confirmation before closing as duplicate

Comment: by the way, even if we consider the link we all know that link-only answers aren't welcome so adding the link as comment should be acceptable and sometimes we don't need to make anything clear because the link itself can be enough. Eveyrone (including me) do this all the time and I don't see such comments as no longer needed especially if it's a documentation link and it's still online

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was thinking that if it was clearer what the link was and why you added it, the comment wouldn't have been flagged as "no longer needed".

Comment: Well, that's kinda silly, isn't it? The flag must be valid, because otherwise they wouldn't have flagged it? By that reasoning, there's no need for mods to be involved at all with nln flags.

Comment: @MikeM. Well, I suppose you could argue it that way, but that's not really what I meant.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really think you did, but rereading your original revision after that comment certainly made it sound so. The edit is better, though.

Comment: @MikeM. As it happens mods don't *have* to be involved with NLN flags... if enough users flag a comment as NLN it will automatically delete!

Comment: @TemaniAfif was the question in your comment one of the ones used as a dupe target ultimately? And was it deleted before or after you closed the question?

Comment: @TylerH That's true, but I was trying to say that if a moderator is nothing more than a blind `if`-`then`-`else`, we really shouldn't be wasting their time with those non-decisions (which itself is somewhat euphemistic for "they shouldn't be allowed to short-circuit or negate the community's decision, in that case"). That wasn't what Chris ultimately meant, though; I was just pointing out how it could have been interpreted. Sorry if that was stated poorly. I'm starting to think that I don't phrase things as well as I'd like to imagine I do. :-)

Comment: @TylerH I closed the question as duplicate after asking this meta question so my comment got deleted before (even the OP didn't see it) and my comment contains no reference to any dupe target. It was a CSS property (the one that would solve the OP quesiton) plus a link to the documentation.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah, I thought it was a link to a question